# unable to login for customuserstore users in wso2IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I created a jar based from the link https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/pushpalanka/SampleCustomeUserStoreManager-5.0.0/

a)Copied the jar into dropin folder and mysql driver in lib folder,
b)Started the server and clicked on Add UserStore, Selected CustomUserStore from the drop down and created it with all mysql connection details
c)When i clicked on Users and saw the test.com/dinuka and test.com/malinda user, changed the permission to login and logged out as admin.
d)When i am trying to login as test.com/dinuka-dinuka, I get there error as [2020-02-25 17:08:53,712] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin} -  System error while Authenticating/Authorizing User : Error when handling event : PRE_AUTHENTICATION.

I am using wso2is 5.3
Subhash

Comment: Did you try to login mgt console as test.com/dinuka or test.com/dinuka-dinuka ? You   can asign login permission for internal-everyone role and try login using the secondary user which is test.com/dinuka

Comment: One more thing to be noted is if you are trying this jar on IS 5.3.0, please use the kernel version  which is 4.4.11 and build the jar. So it will be compatible for IS 5.3.0

Comment: DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager} -  Error Occurred while getting property values for user : dinuka & profile name : default
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'wso2.um_user_attribute' doesn't exist
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.getUserPropertyValues(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:955)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.doGetUserClaimValues(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:3

Comment: am using 4.4.11 jars , am getting this error DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager} -  Error Occurred while getting property values for user : dinuka & profile name : default
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'wso2.um_user_attribute' doesn't exist
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.getUserPropertyValues(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:955)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.doGetUserClaimValues(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:3

Comment: Seems like you have not overriden all the methods.it searching for default tables to getting user attributes.